# Why can a Hermitian matrix $A$ be written as $\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lambda_j|u_j\rangle\langle u_j|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I've seen this being used in several quantum mechanics texts but I'm not sure of the reason:

> Why are we able to write $N\times N$ Hermitian matrices like $A$
>   having eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ and eigenvectors $|u_j\rangle$ in the
>   form $A = \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \lambda_j|u_j\rangle\langle u_j|$ (I'm following the Dirac notation)? Also, is this fact true *only* for Hermitian matrices?

Could someone point me towards a proof?

Comment: Try diagonalization and spectral decomposition.

Comment: If $\lambda_j$ are real, the matrix is Hermitian.  With $\lambda_j$ allowed to be complex, you have a [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).  Any decent linear algebra text should have proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have learned that every Hermitian matrix $\boldsymbol A \in \mathrm M_N(\mathbb C)$ is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix, then the conclusion would be quickly derived: since $\boldsymbol  A = \boldsymbol U \boldsymbol {DU}^*$, where $$\boldsymbol D = \mathrm{diag} (\lambda_j)_1^N, \quad
 \boldsymbol U = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol v_1 & \cdots &\boldsymbol v_n
\end{bmatrix} 
$$ 
and $(\boldsymbol v_j)_1^N$ are eigenvectors written as $N \times 1$ matrices corresponding to $\lambda_j$, then
$$
\boldsymbol A = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol v_1 &\boldsymbol v_2 & \cdots& \boldsymbol v_n
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & & &\\
& \lambda_2 &&\\
&&\ddots &\\
&&&\lambda_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol v_1^* \\ \boldsymbol v_2^*\\ \vdots \\\boldsymbol v_n^*
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and apply the multiplication of blocked matrices, we have
$$
\boldsymbol A = \sum_1^N \lambda_j \boldsymbol v_j \boldsymbol v_j^*,
$$
or write this in "bra-ket" notation if you want.

Moreover, if given matrix is unitarily diagonalizable, i.e. unitarily similar to some diagonal matrix, then you can always do the things stated above and obtain a similar decomposition.